# android-query, downloading images for a listView

Tags: android

I'm using android query to download an image in each element of a listview, and downloading thoses images is very, very, very slow (images far from heavy). I'm like having an image appearing each 5  minutes or so..
First i'm surprise we've got to instanciate one object AQuery for each convertView, I suppose that lib doesn't queu threads this way.. If someone knows a better lib, I could also be intrested

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I hope someone could help !

here is the code of my adapter :

```
private class MainPagerListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Event> dataList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public MainPagerListViewAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<Event> dataList) {

        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.dataList = dataList;
        Collections.sort(dataList, new ALaUneSort());
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataList.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_pager_basic_fragment_item_layout, null);
        AQUtility.setDebug(true);
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(convertView);
        String thumbnail = dataList.get(position-1).file;
        aq.id(R.id.imageView).progress(R.id.progress).image(thumbnail, true, true, 0, 0, null, AQuery.FADE_IN);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Thanks !

Renaud

Comment: are you using lazy loading or anything else?

Comment: are you downloading image from internet, right?

Comment: yes absolutely, and aquery load image from file or cache if it exists

Comment: Android-Query is a lazy loader library, but you should check the documentation for the delayed loading. That sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below Lazy Loading listview's source link for that, it may help you.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)

Comment: I don't understand, it's a project, not a lib ? how do I use it ? Thanks !

Comment: Only Use FileCache.java, ImageLoader.java, MemoryCache.java & Utils.java into your project and write imageLoader.DisplayImage(url(position), mImgViewNews); into your adapter's getview() method.

Comment: I've teste the demo app.. the loading of images is also very long.. maybe it comes from my phone, i'm in wifi.. I don't understand. does LazyList downloaded images will be available offline ?

Comment: so may be your internet speed is slow.

Comment: are the downloaded images available offline with this lib ?

Comment: I don't know about that but image caching concept is used in this.

Comment: Ok, the loading was long cause my app was running in background, now that i've put it in my project instead of android-query, it's way faster ! thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use the ImageDownloader from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/)

Multithreading scenario explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)