# Android - Image not loading properly lazy list

Tags: java, android, lazylist

We are using Lazylist for display the images from web (XML Feed). Small size images are loading properly, but when we try to load large size images (more than 500kb) it throws Out Of Memory exception. What should be the solution for this?.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In that case, catch the exception and try to load the Image with reduced Quality. You can use the Bitmap.Config class for this. By default, it is using Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 for decoding, so try using Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444. If it fails againg, use low quality decoding Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8

Check the sample code to decode using Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true; 
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024]; 
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;

    options.inSampleSize = 1;

    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmapPath, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below Stack Overflow answer's link for lazy loading listview, it may help you and if you have any query regarding that then tell me.

[Lazy Loading Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258675/android-query-downloading-images-for-a-listview/11258956#11258956)