# Add ImageView with AQUERY to ListView

Tags: android, listview, imageview, aquery

i have a working listview with text and want now to add an image with AQuery.

I've changed the XML and added the ImageView element and now want to add load the image by AQuery
Till now i used a SpecialAdapter for the TextViews, but i'm struggling what i have to do to get the Image

my code so far, I think i have to do something with the adapter now like

```
aq.id(R.id.imageView).image(c.getString("URL"), false, false);
```

, but what exactly?

```
package com.schatten.p5_4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class GetArticleList extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = ".MESSAGE";
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TABLE = "Table";
    private static final String A_ID = "AID";
    private static final String A_TEXT = "ArtikelText";
    private static final String A_GROUP = "Fuel";
    private static final String A_PRICE = "Preis_qm";
    private static final String A_IMG_URL = "URL";
    private static String url = "";
    ListView lv;
    TextView aid;
    TextView articletext;
    TextView preis_qm;
    ImageView article_img;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONArray android = null;
    private Context context;
    private AQuery aq;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.article_list);
    oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    url = GlobalDataPool.urlArticleList + intent.getStringExtra(GetArticle.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    new JSONParse().execute();
}

private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        aid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_aid);
        preis_qm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_preis_qm);
        articletext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_articletext);
        article_img = (ImageView) findViewById((R.id.list_image);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GetArticleList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser2 jParser = new JSONParser2();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            android = json.getJSONArray(TABLE);
            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String AID = c.getString(A_ID);
                String ATEXT = c.getString(A_TEXT);
                String APRICE = c.getString(A_PRICE);
                String AIMGURL = GlobalDataPool.imageURL + c.getString("URL");
                // Adding value HashMap key => value
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(A_ID, AID);
                map.put(A_TEXT, ATEXT);
                map.put(A_PRICE, APRICE);
                map.put(A_IMG_URL, AIMGURL);
                oslist.add(map);
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(GetArticleList.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.article_list_v,
                        new String[]{A_ID, A_TEXT, A_PRICE, A_IMG_URL}, new int[]{
                        R.id.tv_aid, R.id.tv_articletext, R.id.tv_preis_qm, R.id.iv_url});


                lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                                      int position, long id) {
                                                  //Toast.makeText(GetArticleList.this, "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                                  Intent intent = new Intent(GetArticleList.this, GetArticle.class);
                                                  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, GlobalDataPool.urlArticle + oslist.get(+position).get("AID"));
                                                  startActivity(intent);
                                                  finish();
                                              }
                                          }
                );
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Update: SOrry, didn't realize the question about my current SpecialAdapter
here it is and i think i have to manage there the imagae Download with AQuery.
But can someone help me there please?

```
package com.schatten.p5_4;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
private int[] colors = new int[] {0x30FFFFFF, 0x30DDDDDD  };

public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos = position % colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've fixed it with the Adapter below and it works.
Would be nice to get comments for better coding, i'm not sure if i have to do all the stuff in the getView section

```
package com.schatten.p5_4;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
//HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
private int[] colors = new int[]{0x30FFFFFF, 0x30DDDDDD};
private List<HashMap<String, String>> data;

public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    data = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    ImageView list_image;
    TextView aid;
    TextView articletext;
    TextView preis_qm;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.article_list_v, parent, false);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> myitem = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myitem = data.get(position);

    aid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_aid);
    preis_qm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_preis_qm);
    articletext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_articletext);
    aid.setText(myitem.get("AID"));
    articletext.setText(myitem.get("ArtikelText"));
    preis_qm.setText(myitem.get("Preis_qm"));

    String myUrl = myitem.get("URL");

    if (myUrl.toLowerCase().contains("jpg")) {
        list_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        AQuery aq = new AQuery(convertView);
        aq.id(list_image).image(myitem.get("URL"), false, false, 200, 0);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should set AQuery in getView() method of your adapter. Can you add your adapter's code?

Comment: All i have is the defined adapter that you see defined with         SpecialAdapter adapter.... So what should i do there?

Comment: You should create your adapter extending BaseAdapter. And then in getView() method you should use AQuery. Here's example how to create own adapter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258675/android-query-downloading-images-for-a-listview

Comment: But isn't there a way to grab the actual ImageView in the SpecialAdapter and then work directly with this refence in AQuery. Buildin an extra getView on this state sounds very complicate